# Including Cron/Crontab in my Bash Backup Script with inputs

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Im doing a Bash-Backup Script with 3 Options:

1. Do fullbackup
2. Do fullbackup at a specific time with cron

First I want to ask for the path like: `Path of directory: /home`

Then i want the hour for the backup: `Hour for the backup (0:00-23:59) : 2:00`

Then a simple question like: `The backup will execute at 2:00. Do you agree(y/n)`

I know how to do a `crontab` but I have no idea how to include that in my script so that I choose option 2 and then the script asks me for the directory and time and set then the `crontab`.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the existing crontab with

```
crontab -l
```

and install a new crontab with

```
crontab file
```

So your script would probably need something like

```
crontab -l | grep -v "# install-backup-script" > /tmp/file.$$
echo "$min $hour * * * /full/path/to/script # install-backup-script" >> /tmp/file.$$
crontab /tmp/file.$$
rm -f /tmp/file.$$
```